# conditional Agreegate of count month wise in a dataset using R

Tags: r, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I have a dataframe with column values as Job_code, Months, Days.

I need the months to be aggregated with condition on Days like (<=30, between 30 to 60, >60)

Normal aggregate function gives only the data aggregated month wise with functions (but I dont see such conditional aggregation)

Input Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
            'Job Code' = c(1,1,8,9,1,1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,6,7,2,3,4,8,4),
            'Months' = c('Apr', 'May','Mar','Jan','Feb','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Dec','Nov','Oct','Oct','Nov','Sep','Jun','Jul','Apr','Mar','May','Jan','Feb','Dec'),
            'Days' = c(30,30,60,80,30,30,60,80,30,30,60,80,30,30,60,80,40,50,90,60,80,40,50)
          )
```

Output has to be:

```
Months 0-30 30-60 >60 Total 
Jan 0 0 2 2 
Feb 1 1 0 2 
Mar 0 1 1 2 
Apr 1 1 0 2 
May 1 1 0 2 
Jun 1 0 1 2 
Jul 0 2 0 2 
Aug 0 0 1 1 
Sep 1 1 0 2 
Oct 1 0 1 2 
Nov 1 1 0 2 
Dec 1 1 0 2 
Total 8 2 5 23
```

Please Forgive on the alignment, as its getting changed once I hit save or submit

The Output columns has to be like Months, <=30 days, 30 to 60 days, >60 days with count aggregated with respect to months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `group` column in the data frame itself and then count based on that:

`df$group <- ifelse(df$Days <= 30, "0-30", ifelse(df$Days <= 60, "30-60", ">60"))`

```
table(df$Months, df$group)

      >60 0-30 30-60
  Apr   0    1     1
  Aug   1    0     0
  Dec   0    1     1
  Feb   0    1     1
  Jan   2    0     0
  Jul   0    0     2
  Jun   1    1     0
  Mar   1    0     1
  May   0    1     1
  Nov   0    1     1
  Oct   1    1     0
  Sep   0    1     1
```